Bind: Socket operation on non-socket. UNIX Sockets
While the Socket itself is initialized, Binding Socket refused to bind returning -1 (socket operation on non-socket). Socket code:
#include "Socket.hpp"

Network::Socket::Socket(int domain, int service, int protocol, int port, unsigned long interface) {
    // Defining address structure
    address.sin_family = domain;
    address.sin_port = htons(port);
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(interface);

    // Establishing connection
    // Establishing socket
    int sock = socket(domain, service, protocol);
    int reuse = 1;
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&reuse, sizeof(reuse));
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, (const char*)&reuse, sizeof(reuse));
    std::cout << "Testing Socket" << std::endl;
    test_connection(sock);
}

// Test the connection TODO: maybe change this
void Network::Socket::test_connection(int to_test) {
    std::cout << "in test connection " << to_test << std::endl;
    if (to_test < 0) {
        perror("Connection failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

// Getters
struct sockaddr_in Network::Socket::get_address() {
    return address;
}

int Network::Socket::get_sock() {
    return sock;
}

Binding Socket code:
#include "BindingSocket.hpp"

// Constructor
Network::BindingSocket::BindingSocket(int domain, int service, int protocol, int port, unsigned long interface) : Socket(domain, service, protocol, port, interface) {
    connect_to_network(get_sock(), get_address());
    std::cout << "Testing BindingSocket " << std::endl; 
    test_connection(binding);
};

// Definition of connect_to network
void Network::BindingSocket::connect_to_network(int sock, struct sockaddr_in address) {
    binding = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address));
}

Here's the Server initializer (to see what I actually put into socket when initialized):
#include "TestServer.hpp"
Network::TestServer::TestServer() : SimpleServer(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, 80, INADDR_ANY, 10) {
    launch();
}

// Accepts the connection
void Network::TestServer::accepter() {
    struct sockaddr_in address = get_socket()->get_address();
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    new_socket = accept(get_socket()->get_sock(), (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t *)&addrlen);
    read(new_socket, buffer, 3000); // should store the request in the buffer
}

// Handles the connection
void Network::TestServer::handler() {
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}

// Responds to the connection
void Network::TestServer::responder() {
    char *hello_msg = "Hello from server";
    write(new_socket, hello_msg, sizeof(hello_msg) - 1); // Could not figure out a workaround, predefined function requires const void *__buf as well as size_t __n, although they are deprecated (gcc will give a warning, ignore it)
    close(new_socket);
}

void Network::TestServer::launch() {
    while(true) {
        std::cout << "IDLE" << std::endl;
        accepter();
        handler();
        responder();
        std::cout << "COMPLETED" << std::endl;
    }
}

I am very confused as to why this doesn't work.
After googling the issue I tried to reset the port and address (as can be seen in the Socket.cpp), but it didn't work. Also two other socket types do not work, not only Binding: Listening and Connecting sockets. I am guessing that the problem has the same root for all three but can't find it myself. All show the same issue: socket operation on non-socket. Please, help!

You have int sock = socket(domain, service, protocol); in your Network::Socket constructor so you're initializing a local variable -- not the  class member named sock as returned by Network::Socket::get_sock.

this hurts. Thank you @G.M. you are a lifesaver
